# Unable to remove global package

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

Trying to remove a global package and it doesn't seem to be removing it.

```
$ eslint -v
v1.10.3
$ npm uninstall eslint -g
$ sudo npm uninstall eslint -g
$ eslint -v
v1.10.3
$ sudo eslint -v
v1.10.3
$ which eslint
/usr/local/bin/eslint
```

You can see that eslint is still at version 1.10.3. Why is this not deleting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't uninstall global npm packages after installing nvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763783/cant-uninstall-global-npm-packages-after-installing-nvm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what happens is that npm is trying to remove it from one place but you have it still installed somewhere else.

This is a problem when e.g. the `npm` program uses `#!/usr/bin/env node` in the shebang line instead of the exact patch to the `node` binary for which it was installed (common for binary installations of Node) especially when you have many versions of Node installed in many places.

See what is the result of:

```
which node
which npm
cat `which npm` | head -1
cat `which eslint` | head -1
ls -alp `which npm`
ls -alp `which eslint`
cat $PATH
```

and try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: `$ ls -alp which eslint
lrwxr-xr-x  1 m089269  admin  40 Jan  8  2016 /usr/local/bin/eslint -> ../lib/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js`. I just manually removed it from this directory

Comment: npm might be preventing you of uninstalling this module since it is needed by some other else. In my case, I had to remove the "babel-loader" in order to remove the "babel-core"